# Should I, and how do I incorporate Microdata into my ASP.NET website with 47 pages?

Tags: seo, microdata, asp.net, schema.org

I have an ASP.NET (VB) with 47 pages. The problem is that it’s in 10 different languages, although 98% just use English. I have 5 master pages.  I’ve read Google Webmaster Tools, but I’m still confounded.

I’m reading about how Microdata is the way to go.  Does this mean I should put `itemtype and itemprop` `span` and `div` tags in my master pages, or should I do all of my 47 pages (.resx resource files) separately?  The main key phrase I want throughout search results is "machine vision".

For instance, the first couple sentences on my "about.aspx" page are:

```html
<span itemprop="name">USS Vision Inc.</span> (USS) is a privately-owned company 
with headquarters in <span itemprop="locality">Detroit, Michigan, USA</span>. We 
design, engineer, produce, and integrate special machine vision 
error-proofing products and <a href="http://www.ussvision.com/services/" 
target="_self" itemprop="url">services</a> that create lean factories by improving 
the quality of manufactured products, and by significantly reducing manufacturing 
costs through advanced automation.
```

Am I doing this right, or how would I do this if I’m not? Should I use the `itemprop="url"` or other Rich snippets for every link in my website?  I mean, do I need to add an `itemprop` to just about everything, or can I just alter my master pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where possible, amend your website's template files to use microdata. For example, in most implementations, it should be straightforward to add microdata to common elements like titles, images and so on. However, weaving microdata into complex pieces of text, like a biography or a news article, can probably only be done on a page-by-page basis in most cases.

Your example code lacks `itemscope` and `itemtype`, which will give the context to your `itemprop`. For example, you've used `itemprop="name"`: name of *what*? The syntax works like this:

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
   <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
 </div>
```

You can see the full example (and others) on the [schema.org website](http://schema.org/Person), and you can test your code with Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

**SEO considerations**

Bear in mind, microdata does not currently have any direct effect on rankings in search. It is used to produce Rich Snippets, which can greatly enhance the attractiveness and usefulness of your search results in Google, but *do not directly enhance ranking* (may very well have an *indirect* influence, though). Here's [Google's Matt Cutts talking on this subject](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OolDzztYwtQ) just this month.

However, the fact that Google, Bing, Yahoo! et al. are developing and supporting schema.org suggests that it will do more in the future, so it's certainly worth experimenting with beyond what's currently documented as having an effect.

Comment: Hello @GDav.  Thank you for taking the time to read and respond to my question!  Your post really cleared up a lot of confusion I had about microdata.  I understand now how it doesn't directly increase your SERPS, but makes it more attractive for an end-user to click your link in a SERP.  I guess 5 years ago when people were saying social media was a good thing, I'm glad I listened.  Likewise, I think I'm going to take a chance on the schema.org thing, as it seems to be the future.  Thank you again for the taking the time to provide the information and helpful links!

Comment: @JasonWeber - No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @Gdav -- I just tested it, and it's working!  It's tedious and a lot of work, but I think it's worth it.  I remember 6 years ago when people said social media would be the next big thing.  I'm glad I listened.  I think schema.org and microdata with rich snippets will, like you said, lead to more clicks and perhaps even indirectly help your SEO.  Thanks again for your help!